# How does the outer variable in this recursive program not getting reset each time

Tags: javascript, recursion, data-structures, dynamic-programming, shortest-path

Below is the program to find the shortest combination to achieve the target sum from a given list of array.

For e.g,
Target sum is `5`,
and list of array is `[2, 3, 5]`

So possible output is `[2, 3]` and `[5]` out of which `[5]` being the shortest is the answer.

Now here's my query:

1. As per my interpretation `shortestCombination` gets reset to `null` on each recursive calls, i.e `bestSum(5, numbers)`, `bestSum(3, numbers)`, `bestSum(1, numbers)` etc. But how does it magically equate to being `[3]` and then `[3, 2]` (instead of `null`) and finally gets replaced with `[5]`?

```js
const bestSum = (targetSum, numbers)=>{
    if(targetSum === 0) return [];
  if(targetSum < 0) return null;
  
  let shortestCombination = null;
  for(let num of numbers){
    const remainder = targetSum - num;
    const remainderCombination = bestSum(remainder, numbers);
    if(remainderCombination !== null){
        const combination = [...remainderCombination, num];
      if(shortestCombination === null || combination.length < shortestCombination.length){
       shortestCombination = combination;
      }
    }
    
  }
  return shortestCombination
}

console.log(bestSum(5, [2, 3, 5]))
```

Comment: `shortestCombination`  is not a singleton, there is a new instance each recursive call, so nothing is been reset.

Comment: @Keith Can you please elaborate a little bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at a trivial example: `bestSum(4, [4])`.

- The first call sets `shortestCombination = null`, then enters a loop. The loop only iterates the once, and sets `remainder = 4-4 = 0`. Then it calls `bestSum(0, [4])`.

  - This second call sees that `targetSum == 0` and returns `[]`.
- Back in the first call, `remainderCombination = []`. It builds `combination = [...[], 4] = [4]`. Then it checks whether `shortestCombination` is null or short than `combination`. It is null, so it sets `shortestCombination = [4]`. Then the loop ends and the function returns `[4]`.

If that makes sense, then apply it to the next less trivial input: `bestSum(2, [1])`.

- The first call sets its `shortestCombination = null`, calls `bestSum(1, [1])`.

  - The second call sets its `shortestCombination = null`, calls `bestSum(0, [1])`.

    - This third call returns `[]`.
  - The second call sets `combination = [1]`, compares this to its `shortestCombination` (which is `null`) and sets `shortestCombination = [1]`, returning `[1]`.
- The first call sets `combination = [1,1]`, compares this to `shortestCombination` (which is `null`) and sets `shortestCombination = [1,1]`, returning `[1,1]`.

So, yes, each recursive call has its its own `shortestCombination`; there is no magic.

Comment: This makes sense and I'm now able to wrap my head around this. Just some more queries, how is the comparison happening between two possible combinations here? Say, [3,2] and [5] Is it the comparison of same recursion recursion for each of the values, say bestSum(5, nums) for mum 2 and 3 respectively?

Comment: For that one, one set of calls will be `bestSum(5, [2,3,5])`, and it will call `bestSum(3, [2,3,5])`, which will call `bestSum(0, [2,3,5])`. That last call returns `[]`, the middle returns `[3]` and the last returns `[2,3]`. There will be a similar call, starting from `3`, returning `[3,2]`, finally there will be a call `bestSum(0, [2,3,5]`, resulting in the combination `[5]`, which is smaller than `[2,3]` and `[3,2]`, and that's the one that will be returned.

Comment: Couldn't put such a long comment so I have put my explanation as an answer below based on the understanding I gathered from yours. Can you Please verify if my interpretation is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating further on the premise Welbong has set:

Let's run the program for `bestSum(2, [1, 2])`

The loops would run two times for each of `1` and `2`.
Now let's see what happens when it runs for `1`.

`bestSum(1, [1, 2])` is called and put on to the stack which again would run for two times, for `num`, `1` and `2`.

Now running for 1, `bestSum(0, [1, 2])` will be called which returns an empty array and combination gets set to `[...[], 1]` or, `[1]`

Now it again runs for `2`, `bestSum(-1, [1, 2])` but this times it returns null and hence doesn't change the values of `combination` and `shortestCombination`.

So the result of `bestSum(1, [1, 2])` turns out to be `[1]`.

This stack is popped out and now we have `bestSum(2, [1, 2])` and for `num 1`, it has returned `[1, num]` i.e `[1, 1]`

Now `bestSum(2, [1, 2])` runs for `2`
it enters the loop, in turn calls `bestSum(0, [1, 2])`. This again would have run twice for each of the run, however, it returns [] in the beginning itself. So, we have `combination` as `[2]` and `shortestCombination` as `[2]` again.

So now it's time for the final stack to be popped out `bestSum(2, [1, 2])` currently it stores `[1, 1]` that was the result of iteration through `num 1`, in the second iteration for `2`, we have `[2]` and this being the shortest replaces `[1, 1]` and finally `[2]` is returned.

So as it turns out, each recursive call gives the `shortestCombination` that is the shortest array resulting from running `bestSum(targetSum, nums)` for each of the `nums`. Each results serve to the stack below it and finally the first stack popps out which is the result of shortest of the `bestSum(targetSum, nums)` running for each of `nums`.

Comment: Yes, that's right.